# CSS/jQuery - Display: none based on browser size

Tags: jquery, html, css, width

On a website I am developing I have 2 log in boxes.  One is in the sidebar and one floats in a fixed position over to the right of the screen.  If the browser width is above 1360px, I want to only display the login box that is floating off to the right.  If the width is below that, I only want to display the one in the sidebar.

I have been trying to use jQuery to do this:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 if ( $(window).width() > 1360) { 
  $("#sidelog").css({"display": "none"});
 } else {
  $("#memberbox").css({"display": "none"});
 }
</script>
```

The #sidelog is the sidebar login box and the #memberbox is the one that floats.

I'm not sure why its not working - I'm only a beginner! LOL.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You could do that with just CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904018/show-hide-div-based-on-browser-size-using-only-css

Comment: I think you have some other problem...

Comment: It works whenever I decrease my window size and then maximise it again.  It just doesn't work on start up.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
#sidelog { display: block; }
#memberbox { display: none; }
@media (min-width: 1361px) {
    #sidelog { display: none; }
    #memberbox { display: block; }
}
```