# javascript which syntax is better?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code and i want to know which one of the following is better 
the first

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    mnHeight = $('.main-nav').height(),
    navBar = $('.navBar');
    if ($(window).innerWidth() > 767) {
        if (!navBar.css("display", "block")) {
            navBar.css("display", "block");
        }
    } else {
        if (navBar.css("display", "block")) {
            navBar.css("display", "none");

        }
    }
});
```

or this one

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    mnHeight = $('.main-nav').height(),
    navBar = $('.navBar');
    if ($(window).innerWidth() > 767) {
            navBar.css("display", "block");
    } else {
            navBar.css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

and why ?
in my opinion the first code is better because the if statement will excute once , but maybe i'm wrong .

Comment: Please ask you question on [review code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Second one is preferred in my understanding. You can even try something like this: `navBar.css(($(window).innerWidth() > 767) ? "block" : "none");`. Just a shorthand for second approach. You should try css(media queries) for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904018/show-hide-div-based-on-browser-size-using-only-css

Comment: `if (!navBar.css("display", "block")) {` doesn't do what you think it does and makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be operating under the false believe that `if (navBar.css("display", "block"))` tests the value of the display property. It doesn't.

It sets the display property, returns a jQuery object, then tests that.

---

> ```
> if (!navBar.css("display", "block")) {
>     navBar.css("display", "block");
> }
> ```

The above:

1. Set the display to block
2. Tests if a jQuery object is false (it never is)
3. Never sets the display to block again (which would be pointless since you've just done that)

> ```
> if (navBar.css("display", "block")) {
>     navBar.css("display", "none");
> }
> ```

The above:

1. Sets the display to block
2. Tests if a jQuery object is true (it always is)
3. Sets the display to none

So it always sets the display to none, making the if statement pointless.

---

The version with the `if` statements is objectively worse because the `if` statements are pointless and never really test anything.

Both the approaches are terrible though since this can be achieved with CSS media queries which would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd one interacts with the DOM less, and will have no work impact for the browser (no calculations or re-paints etc.) if the property value doesn't change. So, the check in the first example is just extra unneeded work.

Answer (score 0):

I would go partially for the second option.
If navBar is modified only in this piece of code, the second option is much more clear. AND ff navBar is modified in other pieces of code, they should call this exact piece of code. So this part of code should be into a function that is called every time you want to modify navBar.
First option should be used in cases when coding too fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think the overhead of fetching the property to decide whether you should set it is not worth the overhead .. therefore I would write it like this (what correlates to your seconds suggestion):

```
var WINDOW_WIDTH_THRESHOLD = 767; /* should be const in es6 */
var $window = $(window);
var $mainNav = $('.main-nav');

function onResize() {
    var minHeight = $mainNav.height();
    var innerWidthAboveThreshold = $window.innerWidth() > WINDOW_WIDTH_THRESHOLD;
    var display = innerWidthAboveThreshold ? "block" : "none";

    navBar.css("display", display);
}

$window.resize(onResize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else to consider:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    mnHeight = $('.main-nav').height();
    navBar.toggle($(window).innerWidth() > 767);
});
```

According to http://api.jquery.com/toggle/, the statement `$( "#foo" ).toggle( display );` is equivalent to:

```
if ( display === true ) {
  $( "#foo" ).show();
} else if ( display === false ) {
  $( "#foo" ).hide();
}
```

so you show `navBar` when the expression passed into `toggle()` is true.