# Displaying items depending on the size of the div

Tags: css, angularjs, html, dom

I'm writing component which would be used in many widgets in web application. Is there any way to change visibility of elements due to div size?

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
  <div>elements to display when width is less than 400px</div>
  <div>elements to display when width is more than 400px</div>
  <div>another div</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible in for example in css? I read about media queries but visibility of elements depends only on widget size where it's used and nothing more.

Comment: This should give you some good ideas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904018/show-hide-div-based-on-browser-size-using-only-css

Comment: It's all about browser size. Not my case. It depends only on widget's size where it's used.

Comment: With javacript. Ask width of container, if this width, set element to display block etc

Comment: use iframe on your widget and your will be able to do with media query

Comment: are you using bootstrap? you can also use [Grid classes](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp). They will show your content differently on different devices (mobile, tablet, desktop)

Answer (score 1):

I did not run it but I hope you get the idea how to implement it. I dont know of a solution in pure css but with jQuery its not that difficult to implement:

```
if( parseInt(jQuery('.container').css('height')) > 400){
    jQuery('.container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
} else{
    jQuery('.container').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a directive for this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myDirective', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'A'
  }
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth; // init

    /* window width or element width jQLite CSS magic goes here */
    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
      scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth; // re-calculate
      scope.$apply(); // re-draw
    });
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <div my-directive ng-show="windowWidth < 400">
      elements to display when width is less than 400px
    </div>
    <div my-directive ng-show="windowWidth > 400">
      elements to display when width is MORE than 400px
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```